# Angular2 modal with steps

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I'm trying to figure out how to create a simple stepper wizard using [Ngbactivemodal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api), like this (button COMEÇAR = START, PRÓXIMO = NEXT and ANTERIOR = PREVIOUS):

[image]

But I'm new on Angular and I don't know how to create these next/previous buttons, because in the Ngbactivemodal docs there's only close/open methods. Is there any way to do that? If not, how library can I use to achieve this?